# How to use data from list tag that the li tag append to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

here is my jquery:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'fuzzySearch',
  async: false,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    orderid: orderid
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var datas = data.msg;
    $('#showMessage').text(datas);
    var list = data.lists;
    for (var num = 0; num < list.length; num++) {
      var obj = list[num];
      $('#SusakeFzzySearch').append("<li value ='" + obj.ordercount + "' style='list-style-type:none' id='liid'>" + obj.ordercount + "</li>");
    }
  },
  error: function(data) {
    var datas = data.msg;
    $('#showMessage').text(datas);
  }
});
```

[image]

I want to when i click the li tag ,search text display the value from li tag,and li tag  hide.

Comment: FYI, don't use `async : false,`...

Comment: it's javascript specification?

Comment: Ya, deprecated and anyway completly useless